# Find/Replace only in failing tests in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

Is there a way to run a find/replace only over the failing tests in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Only if you create such [scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scope.html) manually and then choose it in Rind/Replace dialog.

Comment: Thx I would love to be able to define such a dynamic scope more easily